What is the best way to create UIControl checkbox programmatically
I need to create UIKit UIControl check box with 3 states (unselected, selected and disabled) programmatically. For states I have 3 images in pdf. Which way is the best, any help appreciated
Saw many examples in storyboards and UIButton inherit but it’s not what I want

"Saw many examples ... but it’s not what I want" -- well, please add some more detail. What was wrong with the (many) examples? What wasn't working the way you want it to work?
